How to convert array of arrays to formatted Excel file in React.js/Node.js?
I have an array of arrays representing a table. It looks something like this -
 [
  ["Name", "Age", "Description"],
  ["John Doe", "26", "<div style='color:red;'>John likes the color red</div>"],
  ["Avery Tom", "28", "<p>Avery's favorite fruits are: <ul><li>apples</li><li>bananas</li></ul></p>"],
  ["Kingsley", "30", "<b>Kingsley loves bold text.</b>"]
]

I want to export the contents of this array as an excel file, keeping all the styles that are defined through the HTML tags - the colored text, the list bullets, the bold and italics, etc. The output in Row 3 Column 3 shouldn't be - <b>Kingsley loves bold text.</b> - but rather - Kingsley loves bold text.
There are plenty of free libraries to export an array of arrays to excel tables (such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) but I couldn't find any that could parse the HTML code (passed in via a string) and apply those styles to the text in any cell.
I am receiving this array of arrays in a Node.js utility file that is a part of a larger React application. This utility file simply defines a bunch of functions and doesn't return any JSX code.So I could be wrong, but I don't think I can return an HTML/JSX table from the utility file and convert that to a formatted excel file, retaining all the defined styles.
Note that only the text has styles applied to them - the border, background colors, etc. are not styled at all.
So what can I do to apply the styles defined via HTML tags in my array of arrays in the exported excel file? I want a free solution, don't want to pay for anything.
Thanks

This is very specific to how the library works. You can start with parsing excel file with formatting you need and check how it's stored in library objects. The docs aren't very specific on how formatted text is handled. Notice there are sheet_to_json and json_to_sheet so this is supposed to work in a predictable and readable way
